# Have no clue how to do these two can someone start me on it?

Tags: trigonometry

1. If the angle $\theta$ is such that $2\pi \le \theta \le 4\pi$ and $\cos\theta = -\frac7{25},$ what is the value of $\sin\frac\theta2?$
2. If $\cos 4x = \frac15,$ what is the value of $\sin 6x \sin 2x?$

Comment: You say you have no clue, but [I don't believe you](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/27933#27933). There is a big difference between not having a clue, and just not knowing how a complete and finished solution ought to begin.

Comment: That's what I meant. I didn't there was such a big difference between those two.

Comment: there is a Pythagorean triple 7,24,25 so $| \sin \theta |$ is quick.

Comment: But to get you started, draw a unit circle, and _see_ what the equations are saying about $x$ and $\theta$. That's a lot easier than trying to manipulate some abstract and algebraic equations. Trig is fundamentally geometric, if you can get some geometry going, the way forward is usually clearer.

Comment: In textbooks, lectures, and even on this site, all you ever see is completed solutions. You rarely, if ever, see all the useless dead ends and wrong calculations people do before they get to their solution. But even though it's hidden away, there is **a lot** of it. So it's not something to be afraid of.

Comment: See [Double angle formulae](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trigonometric_identities#Double-angle_formulae).

Comment: See if you can use the formula for $\cos(2\theta)$ and the fact that $\cos^2 (x)+ \sin^2 (x)=1$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hints for #2:

1. Use the sum to product formula $$\sin A \sin B = \dfrac {1}{2} \left(\cos {(A-B)} +  \cos (A+B) \right)$$ to discover that

> $$\sin 6x \sin 2x = \dfrac {1}{2}(\cos 4x + \cos 8x)$$

2. Since you already have a value for $\cos 4x$, you can write $\cos 8x$ as $2 \cos^2 4x - 1$, to wit $$\sin 6x \sin 2x = \dfrac {1}{2}(\cos 4x + 2 \cos^2 4x -1)$$

Can you finish it from here?

Comment: Can you a little deeper in explaining this?

Comment: I got number two. Can someone explain number one?

Comment: I made a mistake on the formula from product to sum; I've corrected it.